# Where to buy used Nikon lenses in the USA?

Tags: lens, nikon-d90, used-equipment

What are some of the sites available for buying used lenses for the Nikon D-90 camera body?  Do any specialize in Nikon or have enough supply to deeply cover Nikon lenses?

Comment: HELP! What am i missing? This question was edited to read, "in the USA," when the accepted answer is a shop in the UK? As far as i can tell, ordering from **Grays** would require an international call for US customers and shipping to the States is probably costly and slow compared to KEH.

Comment: Question was edited by someone else to say USA, original question did not include that constraint.

Comment: right, shouldn't that edit be rejected or reversed? I mean you accepted the **only** non-US answer, so clearly "in the USA" wasn't your intent.

Comment: Well I happen to be in the USA, but would consider a supplier anywhere if the price was competitive, I picked the UK one since they specialized in Nikon.  So I left the edit as is and accepted the non-US answer since from the US you can still purchase from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looking for a used lens I came across [fredmiranda.com](http://fredmiranda.com) and ended up making a purchase through them at a good price.

Answer (score 4):

One I always hear about is [KEH](http://www.keh.com/Camera/format-Digital/system-Nikon-Digital?s=1&bc=40&bcode=DN&bco=497&).  They are in Georgia.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from [KEH](http://www.keh.com/) that MikeW already mentioned, take a look at [Grays of Westminster](http://www.graysofwestminster.co.uk/). I found their collection pretty good and complete. It is an exclusive Nikon shop. The shop is in UK and referred to as "The High Church of Nikon". Their website, unlike other online store websites, is very well organised.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [B&H Photo](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/) - they have all kinds of used equipment, not just lenses.

Their used lens section is [here](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/SLR-Interchangeable-Lenses/ci/10209/N/4294182646) (filters on the left for Brand/Mount/Price/etc)