# What are good websites to buy second hand/after market lenses?

Tags: lens, web, equipment-recommendation, used-equipment

Besides the obvious eBay and Craigslist, are there any good sites for second hand lenses?

Comment: If you want to buy my used lenses, I put them on Kijiji and Craigslist :) I have heard that KEH is popular but never used them, nor do I know what there area of distribution is.

Comment: We also have http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/17383/6789 for Nikon specifically... looks like the answers are the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[KEH](http://www.keh.com/) and [B&H Photo](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/browse/Used-Equipment/ci/2870/N/4294247188) would be the big two in the US.  Other big camera dealers like [Adorama](http://www.adorama.com/catalog.tpl?op=Category&cat1=Used) also sell used gear.

B&H offers a 90 day warranty on used gear.  KEH has a 6 month warranty and 14 day no questions asked return policy

Comment: I'd extend this answer by saying that for some purposes, there are meta-sites that look at some of the used sites, like http://www.canonpricewatch.com/used/.  I can't say I've ever seen KEH show up there, which may be a foible of the site but the warranties/return policy @MikeW mentions sounds good.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.fredmiranda.com/forum/board/10

Comment: Why the markdown?  I've bought and sold many lens on Fred Miranda without a problem.

Comment: I didn't vote down, but I assume it's for putting a link without saying anything about it.